# Is 'Additionally, I would like to inform you that the room I want to rent for two people' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

Additionally, I would like to inform you that the room I want to rent for two people.

Comment: Perhaps either *Additionally, I would like to inform you that I want to rent a room for two people.* (Unless they already know which specific room you're talking about, *a* sounds like the better choice.) Or *Additionally, I would like to inform you that the room I want to rent is for two people.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean to inform someone that the room you want to rent will be used by two people, the word order should be slightly different to avoid confusion:

> Additionally, I would like to inform you that I want to rent the room for two people.

Comment: The typical word order in English is subject, verb, direct object, indirect object.  This is also true in a subordinate clause ("that" indicates a subordinate clause here).